# Hour (Minutes) selection for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

Hi i have this command on my View (_form.html.erb), when im editing the client shows the hours thats fine, but on the minutes shows the 60 minutes of the hour i need to only to show the 0 minute and 30 minute of the hour.

```
    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label "Hora inicio" %><br />
       <%= f.time_select :hora_inicio, {:ampm => true}%>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should really learn to look up the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select) It has it right in there as an example: `time_select 'game', 'game_time', {:minute_step => 15}` Just change 15 to 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `:minute_step` as an option to `time_select()`.

```
f.time_select :hora_inicio, {:minute_step => 30, :ampm => true}
```

This will give you 0 and 30 minutes.